# Asio (non-boost) with Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, boost-asio, djinni

I want to use the non-boost asio (http://think-async.com/) in my project. The project is written in C++, and I use dropbox/djinni to generate the wrappers to Android and iOS. In native C++ asio works fine without includeing boost. But I stucked at the Android part.

In app/build.gradle I added the following lines:

> path/to/asio headers
>   cppFlags += "-DASIO_STANDALONE"

When I build the project, it gives me the following errors:

> compiling src.cpp failed.
>   taps-api\asio\asio\impl\src.cpp:21:3: error: #warning "This file is deprecated."   [-Werror=cpp]
>    # warning "This file is deprecated."
>      ^
>   taps-api\asio\asio\impl\src.cpp:22:3: error: #warning "Please #include <asio/impl/src.hpp> instead." [-Werror=cpp]
>    # warning "Please #include <asio/impl/src.hpp> instead."
>      ^
>   In file included from taps-api\asio\asio\impl\src.cpp:25:0:
>   taps-api\asio/asio/impl/src.hpp:19:3: error: #error Do not compile Asio library   source with ASIO_HEADER_ONLY defined
>    # error Do not compile Asio library source with ASIO_HEADER_ONLY defined

Do anyone know what to do/add? Also I want to ask, can I avoid to include the boost headers/libs in my project (in android/ios)?

I'm using the stable Android Studio 1.3. Also I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135636/how-to-use-asio-standalone-from-boost-in-android-ndk), but it's not solves my problem.

Comment: Have you found a solution since?